# Parágrafo desaparece rapidamente após executar a função

Tags: javascript, html, funções

Olá, gostaria de ajuda com o meu código, estou começando em js. Eu gostaria de mostrar uma progressão aritmética, porém quando executo a função ao clicar no botão, a resposta mostrada no parágrafo com o id "pa" desaparece rapidamente.

Como resolver?

```js
        function mostrar_Pa(){
            var a1 = Number(document.getElementById("a1").value);
            var r = Number(document.getElementById("r").value);
            var pa = "{" + a1;
            var an = a1+r;
            for(i = 0; i<10; i++){
            pa += ", " + an; 
            an += r;
            }
        document.getElementById("pa").innerHTML = pa + "}";
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>PROGRESSÃO ARITMÉTICA</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        Razão: <br><input type="number" id="r"><br>
        A1: <br><input type="number" id="a1"><br><br>
        <button onclick="mostrar_Pa();">Calcular PA</button>
    </form>
    <br>
    <p id="pa"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não declarou o tipo do seu `<button>`. Como ele está dentro de um `<form>`, o button acaba se tornando do tipo `submit`, o que significa que quando você clica nele, o form é enviado e uma nova página é carregada.

Para que o form não seja enviado, declare o tipo de seu button:

```
<button type="button" onclick="mostrar_Pa();">Calcular PA</button>
```

Comment: Bem clara a resposta. Referencia caso queira adicionar a resposta: https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-button-element